# How to use Linux "find" with "-exec" command within an ANT script?

Tags: bash, ant

Consider the following ANT script:

```
<project name="MyProject" default="mainTarget" basedir=".">
    <target name="mainTarget">
        <exec executable="find">
          <arg value="/home/user/Downloads/"/>
          <arg value="-type"/>
          <arg value="f"/>
          <arg value="-exec"/>
          <arg value="dd if=/dev/null of={} \;"/>
       </exec>
    </target>
</project>
```

The output is:

```
Buildfile: /home/user/workspace/ant/build.xml

wrap:
     [exec] find: missing argument to `-exec'
     [exec] Result: 1

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

My main goal is to use ANT to clear the contents of all files in a directory and it's sub-directories. I mean to only clear the files contents, not delete them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `find` program is unusual in that the `-exec` option doesn't take a single argument. Instead, `find` keeps reading arguments after the `-exec` option until it spots an argument that is either a semicolon (`;`) or a plus sign (`+`).

In your example...

```
<exec executable="find">
    <arg value="/home/user/Downloads/"/>
    <arg value="-type"/>
    <arg value="f"/>
    <arg value="-exec"/>
    <arg value="dd if=/dev/null of={} \;"/>
</exec>
```

...Ant wraps quotation marks around `dd if=/dev/null of={} \;` before launching `find`. When `find` runs, only one argument is after `-exec`: `"dd if=/dev/null of={} \;"`. `find` reports an error because there is no argument that is simply `;` or `+`.

To have Ant run `find`, split up the `dd` command into several `<arg>` elements...

```
<exec executable="find">
    <arg value="/home/user/Downloads"/>
    <arg value="-type"/>
    <arg value="f"/>
    <arg value="-exec"/>
    <arg value="dd"/>
    <arg value="if=/dev/null"/>
    <arg value="of={}"/>
    <arg value=";"/>
</exec>
```

Note that the final argument, `<arg value=";"/>`, doesn't have a backslash before the semicolon. The backslash is required when running `find` from a shell such as Bash. However, the Ant script isn't invoking a shell, so there is no need to escape the semicolon.